# touchStart event and queryCommandState delay issues

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari, dom-events, contenteditable

I am working on an editor in iOS that uses `contentEditable`. So, to know what some HTML elements are, I am using `document.queryCommandState()`. This works great, but it actually seems to have a delay when using the `touchstart` event:

```
$('#editor').bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    $('#debug').text('touched');

    if (document.queryCommandState('bold')) {
        $('#debug').text('bold');
    }
    if (document.queryCommandState('italic')) {
        $('#debug').text('italic');
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">

    <p>This is <strong>bold text</strong>.</p>
    <p>This is <em>italic text</em>.</p>

</div>
<div id="debug"></div>
```

When testing on a device, or iOS Simulator, when touching on the bold text, the debug correctly says that the element was touched, but it does NOT say that it is bold. Only touching it a second time does it register as bold.

So, it seems that there is a delay when using `queryCommandState()`. If you tap back and forth between italic and bold it will only show the previous style. E.g., taping bold then italic will say bold, but then tapping bold will say italic.

Demo (make sure you are testing on iOS): http://f.cl.ly/items/3W2A0q451Q00401t3E3G/test.html

**Any idea what is going on any where there is a delay?**

Answer (score 0):

The delay with `touchstart` events is "organic". The device has a small window of opportunity to decide if the touch should be handled in-app/browser (vanilla touch) or in-os (four-finger swipe to switch between open applications). Naturally, the latter has to be handled without side-effects - if you do a four-finger swipe, you don't want to trigger a touch or two on underlying content.

If you must circumvent this behaviour, consider [a broad polyfill](https://github.com/Polymer/PointerEvents) or [FastClick library](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick) that specifically tackles the issue.

Comment: If what you say is true, then why do I instantly see the "touched" text inside my debug div?

Both polyfill and FastClick seem like they would add performance issues to my app. Testing FastClick pretty much renders it useless.